# How to deserialize JSON object with Newtonsoft when it's fields names are reserved keywords like "short"?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, json-deserialization, reserved-words

I have some JSON object:

```json
"opf": {
    "type": "2014",
    "code": "12247",
    "full": "Публичное акционерное общество",
    "short": "ПАО"
}
```

I want it to deserialize it into my class:

```
class SuggestionInfoDataOpf
{
    public string code;
    public string full;
    public string short; //ERROR. Of course I can't declare this field
    public string type;
}
```

I want to deserialize it like

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SuggestionInfoDataOpf>(json_str);
```

but fields names should match.

Comment: name your field `@short`. or name it however you like, and use the [JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) attribute

```cs
class SuggestionInfoDataOpf
{
    [JsonProperty("short")]
    public string Something {get; set;}
}
```

Or using the prefix "@" before the name of the property. Using it you can name a member the same as a keyword

```cs
class SuggestionInfoDataOpf
{
    public string @short;
}
```

But IMO the `JsonProperty` is better, as it allows you to keep to the C# naming guidelines as well as visually separating members from keywords

Answer (score 5):

You should use keywords with `@` like this:

```
class SuggestionInfoDataOpf
{
    public string code;
    public string full;
    public string @short;
    public string type;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Never knew that... ouch... what a shame.